# Django self.cleaned_data.get("field") is None when field value is 0 : why?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a field :

```
models.py
    class MyClass(models.Model) :
    myfield = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and a form validation that handles conditionals controls on multiple fields and must raise an error if self.cleaned_data.get("myfield") is None.

```
forms.py

class VarianteNewForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Variante
        exclude = ('appareil','scenario','published_date', 'version')
        labels = {
            'cas' : "Nom du cas",
            'myfield' : "Dévers",
            'declivite_pointe' : "Déclivité",
            'altitude_pointe_bas' : "Altitude",
        }

    def fields_required(self, fields):
        #"""Used for conditionally marking fields as required."""
        #cf. https://www.fusionbox.com/blog/detail/creating-conditionally-
         required-fields-in-django-forms/577/

        for field in fields:
            if not self.cleaned_data.get(field, ''):
                msg = forms.ValidationError("Please.... " + field)
                self.add_error(field, msg)

    def clean(self):
        option = self.cleaned_data.get("option")
        myfield = self.cleaned_data.get("myfield")
        declivite_pointe = self.cleaned_data.get("declivite_pointe")
        altitude_pointe_bas = self.cleaned_data.get("altitude_pointe_bas")

    if (option == 'pointe') :
            self.fields_required(['myfield', 'declivite_pointe', 
           'altitude_pointe_bas'])

    return self.cleaned_data
```

My problem is :

I want to accept the value "0" as correct.
but when a user inputs 0 for the field myfield, the self.cleaned_data.get("myfield") is None : Why ?
and the form validation raises an error.

Comment: `0` should be a valid value for a `models.FloatField` - please include more information how reproduce the problem.

Comment: please show us the code for your form (especially the `clean` methods).

Comment: added form validation code